# CGAL Update from 4.13 to 5.5

Tags: cgal

I have updated a project using CGAL 4.13 to CGAL 5.5. It uses the kernel:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::FT dbl;
```

and some functions do not compile now anymore. For example the one below:

```
inline void decouple(const dbl& val,dbl& decoupled)
{
   ...
   decoupled=CGAL::Gmpq(val.exact().mpq());
}
```

> ../geometricTools.h:476:50: error: 'const ET' {aka 'const class
> boost::multiprecision::numberboost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_rational'}
> has no member named 'mpq'   476 |
> decoupled=CGAL::Gmpq(val.exact().mpq());

A second problem is a line wher e a string ("123/456") is converted to a number:

```
dbl AlgorithmHdf5::getDbl(int n, int d)
{
...
    dbl ret(m_vDbl[ind]); // argument is a std::string
    return ret;
}
```

> AlgorithmHdf5.cpp:71:36: error: no matching function for call to
> 'CGAL::Lazy_exact_ntboost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_rational
>
> > ::Lazy_exact_nt(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char
> > , std::__cxx11::basic_string >::value_type&)'    71 |                 dbl ret(m_vDbl[ind]);

these lines used to work with CGAL 4.13 but do not with CGAL 5.5. I'd appreciate any help on this. Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Epeck::FT` is a wrapper around some rational type that depends on what is available. If you have GMPXX or LEDA, it may use that. In your case you have GMP and a recent enough Boost, so it uses Boost.Multiprecision. If you disable that with `-DCGAL_DO_NOT_USE_BOOST_MP`, you may get back to the `Gmpq` your old code was apparently expecting.

Boost.Multiprecision does not use reference counting, so `decoupled=val.exact()` should be sufficient for that type. To construct from `std::string`, it may help to first construct a `FT::Exact_type` (or `CGAL::Exact_rational`) and then convert that to `FT`. You may want to file an issue on github about this direct construction from a string, it looks like something that CGAL could support.

Comment: Works now, thank you! BoostMP does not use reference counting, does that mean an exact_predicates_exact_constructions kernel using BoostMP is threadsafe now?

Comment: See https://www.cgal.org/2022/01/31/cgal54/ about thread-safety. FT is still a reference-counted wrapper, but in a "safe" way (and a bit more costly because of atomic operations).

Comment: Thank you. Btw: do_intersect(Triangle_3,Bbox_3) is incorrect in CGAL5.5. Just reported here: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/6808